# shared_ptr and unique_ptr: question about a specific case

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I want to define two classes `A` and `I` in a such a way that their objects respect this kind of relationship:

```
i1 -----------a1
  |------a2
  |----a3
```

- An instance of the class `I` points to zero, one, or many instances of the class `A`.
- An instance of the class `A` points to only one instance of the class `I`.
- An instance of class `I` can be without any instances of class `A`, but an instance of class `A` must have an instance of class `I` "attached".

In order to statisfy these conditions, I declared the two classes as follows:

```
class I;
class A
{
    private:
        std::string as;
        std::shared_ptr<I> iA;        
    public:
        A(std::string aTxt);
        A();
        ~A();
};

class I
{
   private:
       std::string ip;
       std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> as;
       friend class A;
   public:
       I(std::string i);
       ~I();
};
```

And in the source file, I defined the two classes in this way:

```
A::A(std::string aText)
{
    as = aText;
}

A::A()
{
    as = "";
}

A::~A()
{
}

I::I(std::string i)
{
    ip = i;
}

I::~I()
{

}
```

Questions:

1. When the instance `i` of the class `I` is deleted, all the attached instances `a` of the class `A` have to be removed.
   How to set this mechanism in the destructor of `I`?
2. When an instance `a` of the class `A` is deleted, the instance `i` of class `I` that it points to is still pointed by other instances `a` of the class `A`. How to be sure that once all the instances `a` of the classes `A` are deleted, the instance `i` of the class `I` can still exist, even if no instances of `A` point to it?

Comment: Please don't try to post an invalid code: missing semicolons, `unique-ptr`, be consistent with using `std::`.

Comment: *2. When the instance `a` of the class `A` is deleted,  the instance `i` of class `I` pointed to by the deleted `a` of class `A`*. It must never happen by design. `i` owns `a` and only `i` controls `a` life.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes. This was one of doubts about my design. If one `A` can be pointed by only one  `I`, I should write `I` so it directly contains `A`s : what do you mean as "contains": no pointers  within class I to class A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the instance `i` of the class `I` is deleted, all the attached instances `a` of the class `A` have to be removed.
> How to set this mechanism in the destructor of `I`?

The `vector` of `unique_ptr`s will handle that for you automatically. You don't need to write any extra code for it. When an instance of `I` is destroyed, the destructor of the `vector` instance will call the destructor of the `unique_ptr` instances, which will destroy the `A` instances.

> When an instance `a` of the class `A` is deleted, the instance `i` of class `I` that it points to is still pointed by other instances `a` of the class `A`. How to be sure that once all the instances `a` of the classes `A` are deleted, the instance `i` of the class `I` can still exist, even if no instances of `A` point to it?

`A` should not have a smart pointer (`shared_ptr`) to `I` at all, as `A` does not control `I`'s lifetime.  A *non-owning* raw pointer will suffice in this case.

Try this:

```cpp
class I;

class A
{
    private:
        std::string as;
        I* iA;        
    public:
        A(I* i, std::string aTxt = "");
};

class I
{
   private:
       std::string ip;
       std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> as;
       friend class A;
   public:
       I(std::string i);
       void add(std::string aTxt);
};
```

```cpp
A::A(I* i, std::string aText)
{
    iA = i;
    as = aText;
}

I::I(std::string i)
{
    ip = i;
}

void I::add(std::string aTxt)
{
    as.push_back(std::make_unique<A>(this, aTxt));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Remy Lebeau for helping me editing the question, and for answeing it

Answer (score 5):

The way you describe it, the ownership relation is simple - `I` is sole owner of `A` object(s). `A` does not have any ownership over `I` and moreover, it is defined to always have lifetime shorter than the `I` objects that owns it.

So one solution would be to have `I` keep a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>` (or preferably `std::vector<A>` if `A` is not polymorphic) and `A` to accept a raw pointer to `I` in constructor.

```
class I;
class A
{
    private:
        I* iA;        
    public:
        explicit A(I* ownerI) : iA{ownerI} {}
        // no default constructor - you don't want to create invalid objects with no `iA` pointer
        // no user declared destructor - default one is perfectly fine
};

class I
{
   private:
        std::vector<A> as;
        std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> polymorphicAs;
   public:
        // no user-declared destructor - default one will do correct things with either 
        //std::vector<A> and std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>

        void foo() {
            as.emplace_back(this);
            polymorphicAs.push_back(std::make_unique<A>(this));
        }
};
```

Comment: note: use EITHER vector<A> or vector<unique_ptr<A>> not both, depending on whether the unique_ptr is important to you.